# Macport installed py26 - Problem installing independent modules

Tags: python, macos, module, macports

I've installed py26 using macports. I want to install a separate module that isn't on Macports. It gets installed in to my default OSX installation. How do I point my install to my macport installation.

Comment: What happens when you open a new terminal window and run `python`?  Is your python version the new 2.6.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your `PATH` is set up properly for MacPorts Python.  You need to ensure that the Python framework bin directory is on it along with the normal MacPorts bin directories:

```
$ export PATH=opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

If the package is installed by running a command like `python setup.py ...` then you should be all set.  You could be extra sure by using an absolute path to the MacPorts Python:

```
 $ sudo /opt/local/bin/python2.6 setup.py ...
```

If the package is installed with an `easy_install` command, make sure you have installed a version of `easy_install` for the MacPorts Python.  The simplest way to do that:

```
 $ sudo port install py26-distribute  # setuptools replacement, provides easy_install
 $ sudo /opt/local/bin/easy_install-2.6 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Put py26 on your path. In your .bash_profile for instance this should work

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

don't forget to source at the end from the commandline

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the "python_select" port. It will then be easier for you to install packages for your selected python version.

See the discussion in [What is the best way to install python 2 on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5235617/what-is-the-best-way-to-install-python-2-on-os-x)